# floating label problem with ant design and google chrome

Tags: reactjs, next.js, antd

in a project, it was necessary for my input label to be floating. It means that it should be displayed as a placeholder in the input and after typing or clicking, it will go to the top of the input. Like the material UI

i use ant design for my project and i create custom component like this:

form-item.tsx:

```
import { Form } from 'antd';
import FloatingLabel from './floating-label';
import classNames from 'classnames';
import { TFormItemProps } from '@/templates/UI/types';
import { getFieldId, toArray } from 'antd/lib/form/util';

const FormItem = (props: TFormItemProps) => {
  const {
    requiredMessage,
    requiredJustInSubmit = false,
    noLabel = false,
    required,
    labelAlign = 'start',
    maxLength,
    minLength,
    max,
    extra,
    floatingLabel = true,
    className,
    validateFirst = true,
    listName,
    floatingLabelSettings,
    formName = '',
    ...rest
  } = props;
  
  const listNameToArray = listName ? Array.isArray(listName) ? listName : [ listName ] : [];
  const formItemNameToArray = Array.isArray(rest?.name) ? rest?.name : [ rest?.name ];
  
  const inputWatch = Form.useWatch([ ...listNameToArray, ...formItemNameToArray ]);
  
  const mergedName = toArray([ ...listNameToArray, ...formItemNameToArray ]);
  const htmlFor = getFieldId(mergedName, formName);
  
  if (floatingLabel) {
    return (
      <FloatingLabel
        value={ inputWatch }
        label={ rest?.label }
        placeholder={ rest?.placeholder || rest?.label }
        htmlFor={ htmlFor }
        { ...floatingLabelSettings }
      >
        <Form.Item
          extra={ extra }
          { ...rest }
          className={ classNames(
            className,
            '[&>.ant-row>.ant-col>div+div>.ant-form-item-explain]:text-captionMd [&>.ant-row>.ant-col>.ant-form-item-extra]:text-captionMd --floatingLabelFormItem'
          ) }
          label={ null }
        >
          { rest.children }
        </Form.Item>
      </FloatingLabel>
    );
  }
  
  return (
    <Form.Item
      extra={ extra }
      { ...rest }
      className={ classNames('--formItem', className) }
      label={ rest.label }
    >
      { rest.children }
    </Form.Item>
  );
};

export { FormItem };
```

floating-label.tsx:

```
import React, { PropsWithChildren, useState } from 'react';

import classNames from 'classnames';
import { TFloatingLabelProps } from '@/templates/UI/types';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';

const FloatingLabel = ({
  label,
  value,
  placeholder,
  htmlFor,
  children,
  required,
  fixed
}: PropsWithChildren<TFloatingLabelProps>) => {
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  
  const [ focus, setFocus ] = useState(false);
  
  const optionalText = required ? '' : t('Optional');
  
  if (!placeholder) placeholder = label;
  
  if (!required) placeholder = `${ placeholder } (${ optionalText })`;
  
  const isOccupied = focus || fixed || (value && value.length !== 0);
  
  const isOccupiedClass = '!text-captionMd !text-primary-0 !top-[1.5px] pe-[10px] ps-[2px] --asLabel';
  
  return (
    <div
      className="!relative mt-[8px] mb-[-40px]"
      onBlur={ () => setFocus(false) }
      onFocus={ () => setFocus(true) }
    >
      { children }
      
      <label
        htmlFor={ htmlFor }
        className={ classNames('--floatingLabel', { [ isOccupiedClass ]: !!isOccupied }) }
      >
        { (isOccupied) ? label : placeholder }
      </label>
    </div>
  );
};

export default FloatingLabel;
```

and i use this custom component like this:

login-page.tsx:

```
'use client';

import { FormItem, TransitionsComponent } from '@/templates/UI';
import { useHandleAntZodValidator } from '@/utils/helpers';
import { LoginZod } from '@/auth/login/schema/login';
import { Button, Form, Input } from 'antd';
import { FC } from 'react';
import { useHandleLogin } from '@/auth/login/utils/use-handle-login';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';

const LoginForm: FC = () => {
  const { t } = useTranslation([ 'auth', 'common' ]);
  
  const [ formRef ] = Form.useForm();
  
  const handleLogin = useHandleLogin();
  
  return (
    <Form
      form={ formRef }
      onFinish={ handleLogin }
    >
      <TransitionsComponent>
        <TransitionsComponent.Motion id={ 'loginPage' }>
          <FormItem
            name={ 'email' }
            label={ t('Email address') }
            validateTrigger={ 'onBlur' }
            rules={ [ useHandleAntZodValidator(LoginZod) ] }
            floatingLabelSettings={ {
              required: true
            } }
          >
            <Input />
          </FormItem>
          
          <FormItem
            name={ 'password' }
            label={ t('Password', { ns: 'common' }) }
            validateTrigger={ 'onBlur' }
            rules={ [ useHandleAntZodValidator(LoginZod) ] }
            floatingLabelSettings={ {
              required: true
            } }
          >
            <Input.Password />
          </FormItem>
        </TransitionsComponent.Motion>
      </TransitionsComponent>
      
      <Button
        type="primary"
        block
        htmlType="submit"
        className="mt-[30px]"
      >
        { t('Login', { ns: 'common' }) }
      </Button>
    </Form>
  );
};

export default LoginForm;
```

floating label styles:

```
html[lang='en'] {
  .ant-form {
    .--floatingLabel {
      @apply top-[19px];
    }
  }
}

html[lang='ar'] {
  .ant-form {
    .--floatingLabel {
      @apply top-[23px];
    }
  }
}

.ant-form {
  .--floatingLabel {
    @apply absolute pointer-events-none left-[12px] right-[unset] translate-y-[-50%] transition-all duration-[.2s] ease-in z-10 text-[.875rem] text-primary-shade-8;
    
    &.--asLabel {
      &:before {
        @apply content-[""] absolute top-[42%] translate-y-[-50%] start-[-2.5px] bg-neutral-white w-full h-[4px] z-[-1]
      }
    }
  }
  
  &[class*='-rtl'] {
    .--floatingLabel {
      @apply right-[12px] left-[unset];
    }
  }
}
```

if email and password save in browser:
I have a UI problem in Google Chrome as follows:
[image]

and fix this after click on screen or input:
[image]

How to fix this problem for Google Chrome?
This problem does not exist in Firefox!
In fact, I found out that in Firefox, because it puts the data in attribute value, it works correctly. But Google Chrome puts it as a mask and it will not be transferred to attribute Value until you click on the data page!